# Convert json to attribute based xml in python ( Apply tags to multiple root elements , not for child elements)

Tags: python

I need to convert json to attributes based xml in python.I tried **dicttoxml** ===> this is generating xml tags to all child elements which is not my requirement. I tried **xmltodict**  ==> `xmltodict.unparse(res,attr_prefix='')`  This is throwing error like document must have only one root. I don't want common root . I need tags for inner root element.I have json of large data with multiple roots in between . So i cant able to define inner roots in param as a static variable.Is there a way to convert ? Am I missing any params to above function ?

````
    jsonData = [  "folders",
       {}, 
       [
          [  "folder", 
             {   "id": "123",
                 "private": "0",
                 "archived": "0",
                 "order": "1"
             },
          ],
            [  "folder2", 
             {   "id": "456",
                 "private": "0",
                 "archived": "0",
                 "order": "1"
             },
          ]
       ]
    ]
    
    print(dicttoxml(jsonData,attr_type=False,root=False).decode('utf-8'))```
````

Expected output

````
    ```<folders>
        <folder1 id="123" private="0" archived="0" order="1"></folder1>
        <folder2 id="456" private="0" archived="0" order="1"></folder2>
    </folders>```
````

Comment: Can we have any function to do this by not hardcoding root elements in code ?